# How to follow a document.location.reload in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler

I've loaded a page in PhantomJS (using it from NodeJS) and there's a JS function on that page `doRedirect()` which contains

```
...
document.cookie = "key=" + assignedKey
document.location.reload(true)
```

I run `doRedirect()` from PhantomJS like this

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  return doRedirect()
}).then(function(result) {
  // result is null here
})
```

I'd like PhantomJS to follow the `document.location.reload(true)` and return the contents of that new page. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

`document.location.reload()` doesn't navigate anywhere, it reloads the page. It's like clicking the refresh button your browser. It's all happening in the frontend, not the server, where `300 Redirect` happens.

Simply call that function, wait for PhantomJS to finish loading the page, then ask it for the contents.

You can wait for PhantomJS to finish loading by using the [`page.onLoadFinished`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html) event. Additionally, you might need to use `setTimeout()` after load to wait some additional amount of time for page content to load asynchronously.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  // page has loaded, but wait extra time for async content
  setTimeout(function() {
    // do your work here
  }, 2000); // milliseconds, 2 seconds
};
```

Comment: How do I wait for PhantomJS to finish loading the page? Do I need to do something within the `evaluate` function?

Comment: Note that this example code is for plain PhantomJS and *not* a PhantomJS bridge for node.js which OP is using.

Comment: Yeah, the code is by no means definitive, just an example of different ways to handle some async loading.